# Prevent duplicate result MySQL in 2 rows

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a table like this:
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrKen.png)

i would like to display a contact list that who ever talked to me
and the code looks like this

```
<?php
    $list = $link->prepare("SELECT * FROM message WHERE 
                            from = :from AND to != :to
                            OR
                            to = :from2 AND from != :to2
                            GROUP BY from,to
                            ORDER BY timestamp DESC");
$list->bindValue(":from", $row['username'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$list->bindValue(":to", $row['username'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$list->bindValue(":to2", $row['username'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$list->bindValue(":from2", $row['username'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$list->execute();
$result = $list->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($result as $list_chat ) { ?>
```

but it still displays the duplicate
[contact list image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E80Tk.png)

Comment: This code runs as posted? I have to wonder about that, seeing 2 [mysql reserved words, `from` and `to`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html).

Comment: Have you tried the answer below?

Comment: yes but is shows an error

Comment: Did you check that the values don't contain whitespace?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `array_unique()` function to remove duplicates before you display them e.g.

```
$newresult = array_unique($result, SORT_REGULAR);

foreach($newresult as $list_chat ) { ?>
```

Here is more information about `array_unique()`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: it shows an error `Notice:  Array to string conversion in `

Comment: still, there is duplicate sir